# Autolayout UITableViewCell with async UIImageView not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a `UITableView` with pretty basic configuration. The tableview cell contains only one `UIImageView`.

**View Hierarchy:**

[image: View Hierarchy]

I want to present images of different sizes in the `UIImageView`. The width of the `UIImageView` needs to be fixed with a variable height.

Auto Layout should be able to resize the cell automatically but it doesn't work when the images are downloaded asynchronously.

Here is my `cellForRowAt indexPath`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! Cell

    let item = array[indexPath.row]
    let url = URL.init(string: item["imageUrl"] as! String)!

    cell.myImage.image = nil
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let data = try! Data.init(contentsOf: url)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            let image = UIImage.init(data: data)!
            if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? Cell, cell.myImage.image == nil {

                let multiplier = cell.myImage.bounds.width / image.size.width
                cell.heightConstraint.constant =  multiplier * image.size.height

                cell.myImage.image = image

                cell.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

I have a sample project setup on GitHub demonstrating the problem. https://github.com/RishabhTayal/AutoTableViewPOC

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code, you want to adapt the picture height by adaptive cell height

```swift
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 1000
```

Image constraints:

```
Trailing Space to: SuperView
Leading Space to: SuperView
Bottom Space to: SuperView
Top Space to: SuperView
Height Equals:199.5
```

Log printing will show too many warnings

> Note that `func heightForRow` always executes first, then executes `func cellForRowAt`.

If you request a picture in `func cellForRowAt`, you should refresh the cell again after getting the height.I will also remove a vertical constraint, `Bottom Space to: SuperView`

I downloaded `Kingfisher` and used a property to save the downloaded image.

`var urlImages = [String : UIImage]()`

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! Cell

        let item = array[indexPath.row]
        let urlString = item["imageUrl"] as! String
        let url = URL.init(string: urlString)!

        if let cacheImage = urlImages[urlString] {
            cell.myImage.image = cacheImage
            let height = self.view.bounds.size.width * (cacheImage.size.height / cacheImage.size.width)
            cell.imageHeightConstraint.constant = height
        }else{
            cell.myImage.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: nil, options: .none, progressBlock: nil) { result in

                switch result{
                case .success(let value):
                    let image = value.image
                    self.urlImages[urlString] = image

                    let height = self.view.bounds.size.width * (image.size.height / image.size.width)
                    cell.imageHeightConstraint.constant = height

                    tableView.reloadData()

                case .failure(let error):
                    print("error \(error)")
                }
            }
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Refresh will first execute `func heightForRowAt`,now like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        let item = array[indexPath.row]
        let urlString = item["imageUrl"] as! String
        if let image = urlImages[urlString] {
            let height = self.view.bounds.size.width * (image.size.height / image.size.width)
            return height
        }
        return 44
    }
```

Estimated height code also needs to be removed